# How to create a OS X native-looking modal dialog using Swing or AWT

Tags: java, macos, swing

I tried using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog and an AWT Dialog but both just show a dialog window. I want the dialog to look like that of a cocoa app - sliding out from the top of the window.

Comment: See also [Mac Widgets for Java](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Answer (score 2):

Set the Look-And-Feel to the SystemDefault, for OSX it will look native.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
```

There is also a nice LookAndFeel which looks like OSX for other Platforms: [Quaqua Look and Feel](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/)

see [JOptionPane](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/joptionpane.html)

Comment: Well I already have set the system l&f but the dialogs still don't show up as in a native app.

Comment: What does `new JOptionPane().getUI()` says?

Comment: JOptionPane().getUI() says "com.apple.laf.AquaOptionPaneUI"